# How to do dependency injection into an Angular 1.5.x component using ES6 class syntax?

Tags: angularjs, es6-class

I'm using `ng-annotate-loader` to inject dependencies automatically and any other component that I have in my project is working fine, but this implementation of`Datepicker` does not.

When attempting to use `$document`, `$filter` or `$parse` I got `undefined`, that is, dependencies are not being injected.

See on the example below:

```
class DatetimeDirective {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($compile, $document, $filter, DATETIME, $parse, Datepicker) {
    this.$compile = $compile;
    this.$document = $document;
    this.$filter = $filter;
    this.DATETIME = DATETIME;
    this.$parse = $parse;
    this.datepicker = Datepicker;

    this.require = 'ngModel';
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.scope = true;
  }

  link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ..
  }
```

I'm using ES6 to build Angular 1.5.x components.

Is there any other way to inject dependencies in this situation? Perhaps I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong and you can help me to find this.

Component's full code [here](https://gist.github.com/brunowego/e92289f0b85fef62dd990df4b2aa0668#file-datetime-directive-js-L36).

Thank you.

Comment: This site is English only, although we do have a Stack Overflow site in [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @beaker problem solved :{D

Comment: Nice job @LenilsondeCastro!!!

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I thought I was on the site in portuguese. Thanks @LenilsondeCastro